# Safari (iPhone, MacBook) gives NSURLErrorDomain:-1017

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, safari, mobile-safari, websites

I face the issue that Safari returns the error: `cannot parse response (NSURLErrorDomain:-1017)`
I tested it on different iPhones and one MacBook.
iPhone XS & 11 (iOS 14.3). MacBook Pro BigSur.

Google Chrome does **not** have this issue!

Comment: What versions of iOS and macOS are you running on your iPhones and MacBook respectively? When I go to this link in Mojave (10.14.6) in Safari v. 14.0 (14610.1.28.1.10) I get a different error: "The operation couldn't be completed. Protocol error (NSPOSIXErrorDomain:100)"

Comment: iPhone XS & 11 (iOS 14.3). MacBook Pro BigSur.

Comment: I was in touch with the Apple Support and they also don't know how to solve the issue.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if somehow _some_ pages are being deliberately blocked by Safari, for whatever reason. In my case, I was having some trouble logging in to a page (a network problem of some sort), and after insisting quite a while, I started getting that error on Safari. The page works on every other browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you using to host the website?
The issue is because of:

> It looks like your server is offering an upgrade to HTTP/2 even though
> the connection is already done with HTTP/2 - which makes no sense. Not
> only that, it is explicitly forbidden. From RFC 7540 section 8.1.2.2:

I had a similar issue with a .NET API which was breaking only with Safari/iOS and the solution was pretty similar to HTTP/2 configuration

Please check here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/937253/https-doesnt-work-with-safari

*Nginx: Header unset Upgrade; does not work if you proxy your request, use proxy_hide_header      Upgrade; instead.*

Comment: This was absolute correct! Thx!